# .NET Core application running in Linux Docker container cannot access a specific SQL Server

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I am attempting to connect to two MSSQL servers using SQL Authentication. When I run my application on my machine with `dotnet run`, it can connect to both of the databases. When I put the application into a Docker container, the application can only connect to one of the databases. I get no error or timeout. It just sits there at 100% CPU. Both databases are on the same network and I have been told that there is no internal firewall.

I have it logging out its connection string during the `OnConfiguring` step of creating the context and the connection string is correct. I have tried using both the fully qualified domain name of the server as well as its IP address.

Any ideas on why I cannot connect to this server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the resolution. https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3550#issuecomment-538608972 held the answer. Basically I switched over to the alpine variant of dotnet images.

There is an issue with the default images of dotnet apparently.

I also had to add the following to my Dockerfile to get over an error message saying, "Globalization Invariant Mode is not supported."

```
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
```

Comment: This got me past one issue, but now I still have TCP transport errors. I'm using .NET 3.1.x + Alpine 3.12 (3.13 doesn't allow using apk for cert reasons?). Dapper works with a direct query, OData + EntityFramework does not work. Everything works very quickly locally on Windows.